# Zend Framework 2 Form Element Label No Escape

Tags: zend-framework2

I would like to know how to disable escaping on Form Checkbox Element label ?

I would like to have my label html, this is my current code :

```
    $score = new \Zend\Form\Element\MultiCheckbox('score');
    $score->setLabel('Score');
    $score->setOptions(array('value_options' => array(1 => '<b>Test 1</b>', 2 => '<b>Test 2</b>')));
    $score->setAttributes(array('escape' => false));
    $this->add($score);
```

Comment: Never ever use HTML-Markup for Styling purpose. Use CSS to style your labels!

Comment: @Sam - I'm curious as to how you'd achieve that...can you perhaps help with an example? Thanks in advance for a late-to-the-party comment! :)

Comment: @ChrisKempen just take a look at the answer that's accepted. That's exactly what the OP asked for. If you have a similar question, start your own question with more specific details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have a way to short-circuit the HTML escaper. The code on the [Multicheckbox view helper](https://github.com/zendframework/Component_ZendForm/blob/master/View/Helper/FormMultiCheckbox.php) does not allow for a conditional escape. You would need to create your own view Helper in order to render the HTML.

If all you're looking to do is set the labels to bold, however, you can accomplish that with CSS. The 'value_options' option can be an array of arrays where the second level contains options for each individual input in the Multicheckbox. For example:

```
'value_coptions' => array(
  'test_1' => array(
      'value' => '1',
      'label' => 'Test 1',
      'label_attributes' => array( 'style' => 'font-weight: bold' ),
      'selected' => true,
  ),
),
```

Comment: To be honest, I don't remember if I read it on a blog or just from going through the Form/View/Helper source code. At the time a lot of the documentation for view helpers was incomplete or buried in some one's blog post. So digging through the source code was the best way to figure out how things worked.

Answer (score 8):

```
 $score->setLabelOptions(array('disable_html_escape' => true));
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, because only this answer allows html for parts of a label like `'label' => 'This is <strong>my</strong> label'`. This is way more flexible than the accepted answer.